# VSCode multiline select - how to delete without removing blank lines?

Tags: text-editors, visual-studio-code, text-editing

VSCode has the ability to start a multiline selection via:

`shift + alt + mouse drag`

or

`ctrl + shift + alt + arrow key`

The problem is that when I'm working across lines of code with empty lines interspersed, if I backspace to remove code to the start of the line, the empty lines are removed with it:

[image]

becomes:

[image]

How do I get a 'column' selection (as I believe it's called) like with Notepad++'s `alt + mouse drag` / `shift + alt + up/down arrow` that operations purely horizontally across rows (which would preserve the new lines here)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question 'Q & A' style having done some more playing:

I can achieve the desired behavior by starting a selection using:

`shift + alt`

... and then drag the mouse left or right to start a single line selection, AND THEN start dragging down ...

*or* by starting a selection using:

`ctrl + shift + alt`

... and using the left / right arrow key to start a single line selection, AND THEN use the up / down arrows ...

I then get a column / box selection that will not operate on the blank lines in my example above.

Note that (maybe only in my scenario above) I need to start the selection a few characters in to get the column / box selection - starting on the far left doesn't work so well.

This doesn't feel very intuitive at all, but VSCode seems worth it so far!

Comment: Another option: select multiple lines and press <SHIFT>+<TAB> (i.e. "outdent").  It works in that it doesn't delete empty lines, but unfortunately is not exactly the same as "delete".